# invalid date con js

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de configurar una fecha de forma tal que me la tome con dd/mm/aaaa
el problema es que con mi codigo no la esta configurando bien me manda de la siguiente forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces necesito que el formato lo cambie a dd/mm/aaaa

```
 let fechReg221 = new Date(fechReg2).toLocaleDateString("es-MX");
console.log(fechReg221);
```

esta variable fechReg2 me trae la fecha con dd,mm,aaaa

Answer (score 0):

EDITADO:
Lo que necesitas es esto, maneja la fecha y dejala como la necesitas, completa tu los otros meses del CASE, Saludos y vota ;)

```
var dateIn = "23,Dic,2021"
var arrDate = dateIn.split(',')
var monthOut = ''
switch (arrDate[1]) {
 case 'Dic':
    monthOut = '12'
    break;
 case 'Ene':
    monthOut = '01'
    break;
}
var dateOut = arrDate[2]+ '/'+monthOut+'/'+arrDate[0]
console.log(dateOut)
```

---

POST ANTERIOR
Aaah pero viendo bien el tema acá es que estas manejando mal el pase de string a date. El formato de cadena debe ser YYYY-MM-DD, el formato ISO 8601.
Así que debes cambiar tu string a formato  año mes y día. y ahí lo toma.

---

Puedes usar moment para manejar fechas

```
return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Pero si lo quieres hacer de forma nativa usa toLocaleDateString('en-GB')

```
// America/Los_Angeles for the US
// US English uses month-day-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
// → "12/19/2012"

// British English uses day-month-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
// → "20/12/2012"

// Korean uses year-month-day order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ko-KR'));
// → "2012. 12. 20."

// Arabic in most Arabic speaking countries uses real Arabic digits
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG'));
// → "٢٠‏/١٢‏/٢٠١٢"

// chinese
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN'));
// → "2012/12/20"
```

Comment: use GB pero me manda igual invali date 
  let fechReg221 = new Date(fechReg2).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
    console.log(fechReg221);

Comment: Claro el problema es como estas tomando e formato... debes manejar la fecha que te llega, tiron de oreja para quien te manda la fecha así en un endpoint, pero entonces debes modificar el texto que envian, usa un slipt mira te dejo otra respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Porque el formato de la fecha es incorrecto. El formato correcto de una fecha es el siguiente:

```
MM DD YY
```

Es decir, algo así

```
Dec 28 2021
```

Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(new Date("Dec 28 2021"))
```

Además, ten en cuenta que `Dic.` quiere decir Diciembre, está abreviado, sin embargo está en español, lo que tienes que hacer es poner la fecha correcta en inglés para que se pueda leer

Sabiendo esto, es fácil convertirlo al formato que quieres

```js
console.log(new Date("Dec 18 2021").toLocaleString("es-mx"))
```

Con respecto a que viene de una API, puedes separar el string por comas, usando [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), para separar el string por comas, luego convertiremos el mes en español a inglés para que JavaScript pueda interpretarlo

```js
const fechaEsp = "28,Dic,2021";
const mesesEsp = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
const mesesEng = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
const fechaEng = fechaEsp.split(",").map(e => mesesEsp.includes(e) ? mesesEng[mesesEsp.indexOf(e)] : e).join(" ");
console.log(new Date(fechaEng));
```

Comment: es que lo trae de una api que la fecha viene con comas

Comment: @RobertMendoza Se puede convertir la fecha a inglés, usando algo de código simple, he actualizado mi respuesta y no debe de haber problemas con eso ahora.

Comment: EXCELENTE muchisimas gracias me funciono a la perfecccion de esta forma
 const fechaEsp = fechReg2;
     const mesesEsp = ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
     const mesesEng = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
     const fechaEng = fechaEsp.split(",").map(e => mesesEsp.includes(e) ? mesesEng[mesesEsp.indexOf(e)] : e).join(" ");
     console.log(new Date(fechaEng));

     let fechReg221 = new Date(fechaEng).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
     console.log(fechReg221);

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes controlar con Moment

```
moment (fechaConFormatoMMDDYY , 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```